# First element of returned vector is (re)set to 0

Tags: c++, vector, return-value, temporary

I had this problem while using a given library in my software. A function returns a `const std::vector&` which I want to use. However, the first value is always set to zero (or in my original code: a 3D-vector with all coordinates set to 0.0) although the value I stored in it beforehand was not.

The class structure is the following (the example code is below):

- `ValueContainer`: contains a `std::vector< double >` of values and the getter `values()`.
- `Object`: contains a `ValueContainer`, and a getter `valuesContainer()`.

In my code, I retrieved the values with:

```
// First element always set to 0
const std::vector< double >& values = object.valuesContainer().values();
```

This resulted in the error, that the first element was set to `0.0`.
I could circumvent the problem by copying the values:

```
// This works as expected
std::vector< double > values = object.valuesContainer().values();
```

On closer inspection, I noticed, that `valuesContainer()` did not return a reference, but a copy of `ValueContainer`. What happens is (in my understanding), that I call `values()` on a temporary object created by `valuesContainer()` and thus get a reference to a temporary object. This of course will not work well, and I would expect to get 'garbage'-data in my vector, or something like that.

However: All the values except the first one seem to be ok! Now, the real question is: Why does it work like that? If it is just undefined behaviour, why is the first value set to 0 and the others remain the same? I'd be happy to get a little more insight into that matter.

Here now follows the example code, tested with gcc 4.8.1 on linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

class ValueContainer
{
    public:
        ValueContainer();
        inline const std::vector< double >& values() const;

    //private:
        std::vector< double > some_values_;
};

class Object
{
    public:
        ValueContainer valueContainerCopy() const
        {
            return values_;
        }

        const ValueContainer& valueContainerConstRef() const
        {
            return values_;
        }

    //private:
        ValueContainer values_;
};

ValueContainer::ValueContainer()
{
    // Just some test data
    some_values_.push_back(1.2);
    some_values_.push_back(3.4);
    some_values_.push_back(5.6);
    some_values_.push_back(7.8);
    some_values_.push_back(9.0);
}

const std::vector< double >& ValueContainer::values() const
{
    return some_values_;
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Object obj;

    const std::vector< double >& values_CopyRef  = obj.valueContainerCopy().values();
    const std::vector< double >& values_RefRef   = obj.valueContainerConstRef().values();
    std::vector< double >        values_CopyCopy = obj.valueContainerCopy().values();

    std::cout << "Pointers: " << std::endl
              << " - Original: " << &obj.values_.some_values_ << std::endl
              << " - CopyRef:  " << &values_CopyRef << std::endl
              << " - RefRef:   " << &values_RefRef << std::endl
              << " - CopyCopy: " << &values_CopyCopy << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Data pointers: " << std::endl
              << " - Original: " << obj.values_.some_values_.data() << std::endl
              << " - CopyRef:  " << values_CopyRef.data() << std::endl
              << " - RefRef:   " << values_RefRef.data() << std::endl
              << " - CopyCopy: " << values_CopyCopy.data() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Data:" << std::endl;
    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < values_RefRef.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "i=" << i << ": " <<  std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
                  << "CopyRef: "  << values_CopyRef[ i ] << ", "
                  << "RefRef: "   << values_RefRef[ i ] << ", " 
                  << "CopyCopy: " << values_CopyCopy[ i ] 
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The (important) output of this example is the following, where you can see, that the first value of the reference to the temporary object is set to 0 and the other values seem fine:

```
i=0: CopyRef: 0.0, RefRef: 1.2, CopyCopy: 1.2
i=1: CopyRef: 3.4, RefRef: 3.4, CopyCopy: 3.4
i=2: CopyRef: 5.6, RefRef: 5.6, CopyCopy: 5.6
i=3: CopyRef: 7.8, RefRef: 7.8, CopyCopy: 7.8
i=4: CopyRef: 9.0, RefRef: 9.0, CopyCopy: 9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const std::vector< double >& values_CopyRef  = obj.valueContainerCopy().values();
```

That is storing a reference to a temporary because the `valueContainerCopy` function is declared as

```
ValueContainer valueContainerCopy() const
{
    return values_;
}
```

Which will copy the vector `values_` into a temporary vector that is returned.  You are then storing a reference to data in that temporary, resulting in undefined behavior.

If you want to store it as a reference, you need to return a reference, which is what you do in the `valueContainerConstRef` function.

Comment: I knew that, but still thanks for the answer. But I'd still like to know, why exactly there's a zero at the first position in the vector (or at the memory position where the temporary vector's first element used to be). And while "undefined behaviour" might be the answer, this doesn't really satisfy my curiosity ;) Might it have smth. to do with the destruction of the temorary's vector?

Comment: The simple answer is undefined behavior is undefined.  As a couple of other contributors would say:  It could order you a pizza ... since it isn't defined, anything that happens is going to be "correct" for that system.